# Stopping time for a Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains, stopping-times

Let $X_n$ be a **recurrent** Markov chain with states $\mathbb N$. Let $T$ be the time of first arrival in $\{1\}$. Is it true that starting from any state
$$\mathbb E[X_{min(T,n)}]\to \mathbb E[X_T]=1?$$
my teacher justified it with the dominated convergence theorem, but I don't understand why. Of course $X_{min(T,n)}\to X_T$ pointwise but how can we say that there is $Y\in L^1$ such that $Y>X_{min(T,n)}$ almost everywhere?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Clearly $\mathbb E[X_T]>0$ when conditioned on $\{X_0\ne 1\}$.

Comment: I made a mistake, it is $\mathbb E[X_T]=1$ since $X_T=1$ a.s. by definition of $T$

Comment: Maybe it works if all the states are fast recurrent?

Comment: I think you can get a counterexample with a chain that begins by jumping to a random state $Z$, where $E[Z]=\infty$, and then moves uniformly to the left after that.

Comment: I don't see any reason to believe that $\mathbb E[X_T]=1$. Especially if conditioned on a state $i$ with $P_{i,1}=0$.